# Add Class to Image On Click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class of 'nocheck' to a specific image with class of 'check' when clicked. Below is my code so far, which does not produce the desired result. Please let me know what I am doing incorrectly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.check").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("nocheck");
    });​
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You're adding this on document ready right?

Comment: Yes, edited code in question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of it where it doesn't work, I feel like what you did should be fine.

Comment: What is your "desired result"? Maybe your CSS rule for `.check` have more weight then for `.nocheck`?

Comment: Yes @WalterStabosz. Here is the Fiddle, which seems to work (except it does not remove nocheck class on second click): http://jsfiddle.net/ecF6b/1/. Any idea why this isn't working on my local machine? I've linked to the jquery script.

Comment: the problem is the click event cannot fire once the image is no longer visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Igor is right, your codes is written correctly. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zZx8P/2/). It shows your code in action. My guess is that some style in your .nocheck class is being overridden by the same style in your .check class. Note the use of the !important flag in the css of my fiddle.

Do you know how to use Chrome's debugger tools? You can use it to easily investigate your DOM. I suspect that your code is working and you don't even realize it. The DOM inspector will easily show you the class attribute of your image element, so you will know exactly what's happening. You can also use it to set breakpoints in your javascript to confirm that events are firing.

Comment: I've been using Firebug to inspect this element before/after click and the nocheck class is not being added.

Comment: Walter, that works well, but it toggles 'nocheck' on all instances of img.check, not just the one inside the specificfriend_box that was clicked.

Comment: I moved the event to div.friend . Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/find/ to understand how it works. See updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ecF6b/6/

Comment: no problem. Check out Chrome's debugging tools when you get a chance. I used to use Firebug, but Chrome won me over after I had lots of issues with Firebug debugging js. Firebug does do some things better however, I like its CSS editor better, and its auto-complete on the js console is better.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove old class of this image like there:

http://jsfiddle.net/zZx8P/

Comment: What if I want it to be in addition to the original class?

Comment: well, if you want to just add new class to img, your code in first post is correct. But for what you are adding new class?

Comment: You have to either remove old class or write your css accordingly (ie - img.check.nocheck{styles}

Answer (score 0):

You might need to remove "check" at the same time you add "nocheck".  Use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$(this).toggleClass("check nocheck");
```